# $e^{5 \frac{2 \pi i}{6}}+e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{6}}=1$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, exponentiation

Why is $e^{5 \frac{2 \pi i}{6}}+e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{6}}=1$?

I know $e^{5 \frac{2 \pi i}{6}} = e^{-\frac{\pi i}{3}}=\overline{e^{\frac{\pi i}{3}}}=\overline{e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{6}}}$, but I still don't see why the equation is true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint.

Note that for any complex number $z$,
$
z+\overline{z}=2\textrm{Re}(z)
$.
Also $\textrm{Re}(e^{i\theta})=\cos(\theta)$ for $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$.

Now observe that $\cos(2\pi/6)=\frac12$.

Answer (score 1):

Because $(\mathbb{Z} / 6 \mathbb{Z},+) \to (E_6,\cdot)$ with $E_6 = \{ e^{\frac{2 \pi i k}{5}} : k = 0,1,\dots,5 \} $ is a group isomorphism, the statement follows because $5+1=6=0$ in $\mathbb{Z} / 6 \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: While the answer is correct, I think thet tag "algebra-precalculus" requires a more straight-forward answer.